# Is params Keyword supports with ValueTuple as a parameter C# 7.0?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples, c#-7.0, valuetuple

I search in *StackOverflow*, don't find any articles or anything related to that.

For example, the following example describes *array of* **ValueTuple**

```cs
(string CategoryName, params string[] Properties)[]  MyArrayValueTupleParameter  // Compile-Time Syntax error
```

Note that the previous example used as a parameter. not a variable.

But only `string[]` works without params? Did I missed something here or is it not supported by default?

**At a glance:**

This Works

```cs
void ShowAppearanceCategories((string CategoryName, string[] Properties)[] VisibleCategories)
{
    foreach (var Row in PropertyGridControl.Rows)
    {
        var VisibleCategory = VisibleCategories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryName == Row.Name);
        if (VisibleCategory != default)
        {
            foreach (var ChildRow in Row.ChildRows)
            {
                if (VisibleCategory.Properties.Any(x => ChildRow.Name.Contains(x)))
                {
                    ChildRow.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

This Doesn't Work

```cs
void ShowAppearanceCategories((string CategoryName, params string[] Properties)[] VisibleCategories) // Syntax-Error
{
    foreach (var Row in PropertyGridControl.Rows)
    {
        var VisibleCategory = VisibleCategories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryName == Row.Name);
        if (VisibleCategory != default)
        {
            foreach (var ChildRow in Row.ChildRows)
            {
                if (VisibleCategory.Properties.Any(x => ChildRow.Name.Contains(x)))
                {
                    ChildRow.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `params` in the definition of a value tuple.  It can only be used to modify the last argument in a method (and the argument has to be an array).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *parameter array* is a very specific language feature that is only applicable to *method parameters*. A *value tuple* is a struct with variable length generic parameters and has been given a special syntax for initialization and usage (most of which are just smoke an mirrors).

```
var asd = ("asd","asd");
```

Is basically just syntactic sugar for

```
ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple = new ValueTuple<string, string>("asd", "asd");
```

There isn't even anything overly magical about named tuples.

```
var asd = (bob1 : "asd", bob2 : "asd");
Console.WriteLine(asd.bob1);
```

Basically converts to the following

```
ValueTuple<string, string> valueTuple = new ValueTuple<string, string>("asd", "asd");
Console.WriteLine(valueTuple.Item1);
```

So you are essentially asking, why you can't use `params` in a tuple initializer syntax.

Well, as discussed, because a value tuple initializer actually isn't a method, and as much as it looks like it, the arguments you give it are not a method parameters. Tuple syntax is it's own very special language feature. However, you do have options.

So let's look at what you are trying to achieve. If you had a method parameter as such

```
public void Test((string arg1, params string[] args) tuple)
```

the only advantage would be you could supply a comma separated list.

```
Test(("bob","args1","args2","args3"));
```

Since we can't, your options are

```
Test(("bob",new []{"args1","args2","args3"}));
```

Or with some tomfoolery you could use an explicit operator on your own struct.

```
public readonly struct Testing
{
   public Testing(ITuple x)
   {
      CategoryName = (string) x[0];
      Properties = EnumerateTuple<string>(x).ToArray();
   }
   public Testing(string categoryName,string[] properties)
   {
      CategoryName = categoryName;
      Properties = properties;
   }

   private static IEnumerable<T> EnumerateTuple<T>(ITuple x)
   {
      for (var i = 1; i < x.Length; i++)
         yield return (T) x[i];
   }
   public string CategoryName { get; }
   public string[] Properties { get; }
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string[]) x) => new Testing(x.Item1,x.Item2);
   public static implicit operator Testing(string x) => new Testing(x, Array.Empty<string>());
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string,string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
   public static implicit operator Testing((string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string) x) => new Testing(x);
}
```

Which would allow shenanigan's such as this

```
public static void Test(Testing something)
{
   Console.WriteLine(something.Category);
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", something.Properties);
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Test("asd");
   Test(("asd"));
   Test(("asd", "args1"));
   Test(("asd", "args1", "args2"));
   Test(("asd", new []{"args1", "args2"}));
}
```

<sub>***Note** : This was only for academic purposes, I really wouldn't expect anyone to want to do this*</sub>

Comment: You took many efforts on that.. And I guess its very good to test your code above later. Thanks you got it.

Comment: Great explanation, get an up vote from me if only for the use of `tomfoolery`

Answer (score 2):

In the method signature, the params keyword must be preceded by the start of the arguments list or a previous argument. It must be followed by the type of the additional parameters.

so:

`ReturnType MethodName(/* arguments */, params Type[] containingArrayName) { /* method body */ }`

In your signature you can see that the `params` is not at the start of a parameter declaration:
`void ShowAppearanceCategories((string CategoryName, params string[] Properties)[] VisibleCategories)`

The extra bracket `(string CategoryName, params string[] Properties)` here makes it closer to a tuple type, inside of which the `params` keyword is not allowed causing a syntax error.

I'm not sure what you're after but it seems to be this:

```cs
void ShowAppearanceCategories(params (string CategoryName, string[] Properties)[] VisibleCategories)
```

Comment: You are right in modified ShowAppearanceCategories method. but I think what I need is not supported for ValueTuple... maybe in dream future they can support params in ValueTuple.

Comment: @deveton: _"maybe in dream future they can support params in ValueTuple"_ -- that would make no sense. The `params` keyword is _strictly_ for allowing variable length method parameter lists. Your proposed usage is completely different and has nothing to do with method parameter lists. Furthermore, since types themselves have no mechanism for allowing variable-length generic type parameter lists, there is likewise no mechanism for `params` to make sense in a generic type parameter list (which is effectively what you'd be doing in the case of `ValueTuple`).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is right in front of you...

The `params` keyword, very well explained by the the other answers here, *enables* a method to receive an array of objects (in your case `string[]`). Whether the caller of your method passes 1 string or 100 strings, your method will get a string array. This is simply *syntactic sugar* to make our lives as developers easier.

*However* your `tuple` *already has* a string array:

```
(string CategoryName, string[] Properties)
```

You don't *need* the `params` keyword, because you already have the structure you need: `string[]`.

Or maybe this will explain it better: these two methods are the *same*:

```
void DoSomething(string[] Properties) {...}

void DoSomething(params string Properties) {...}
```

With both of these method signatures you will reference the `Properties` argument as a `string[]`.

Please let me know if I am not being clear.